# UITableviewcell behaviour duplicated and inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UItableview cell, whose data I am fetching from firebase. i have 2 issues:

1. My label is of different sizes when we scroll back to that indexPath.

i am performing the following code, but still unable to understand the behaviour. I even tried removing cell subview, but that just doesn't load the cells in the tables.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell") as? FeedCell {

        cell.caption.text = nil
        cell.configureCell(post: post)// sets the caption text here!
        cell.caption.sizeToFit()
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    } else {
        return FeedCell()
    }
}
```

2. I am animating a view on a cell every time a cell is in view. But whenever I perform it, The animation is for all the cells. What is the possible fix for that? the code:

   ```
   class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var caption: UILabel!

   @IBOutlet weak var activityindicator: NVActivityIndicatorView!



   var usersender: User!
   var posts: Posts!
   var viewRef: DatabaseReference!
   var users: User!

   var delegate: FeedCellDelegate!

   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

   }

   func setDelegate(delegate: FeedCellDelegate) {
       self.delegate = delegate
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()


       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(animateIndicator), name: .animateIndicator, object: nil)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopIndicator), name: .stopIndicator, object: nil)
   emotionDisplay.alpha = 0.0

       caption.addDropShadow(opacity: 3, radius: 8)


   }


   @objc func animateIndicator(note: Notification){
       activityindicator.startAnimating()
   }

   @objc func stopIndicator(note: Notification){
       activityindicator.stopAnimating()
   }





   @IBAction func gotoprof(_ sender: Any) {
       self.delegate.segueToUser(user: usersender)
   }




   func configureCell(post: Posts, img: UIImage? = nil) {

       self.posts = post
       self.caption.text = posts.caption

   }

   }
   ```

please point me the right direction.

Comment: All cells is observing the same Notification, thats why all cell is animating when you post the notification, just get the right single cell to call the function

Comment: thanks for the response. How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Tj3n wrote - all cells observing the same Notification.

The easiest way is to create second class for that cell you want to animate with code you wrote in FeedCell class.

For other cells just remove from awakeFromNib() :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(animateIndicator), name: .animateIndicator, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopIndicator), name: .stopIndicator, object: nil)
```

And awakeFromNib() should looks:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    caption.addDropShadow(opacity: 3, radius: 8)
}
```

Comment: i get your point. My cells do animate each time they are in view when a particular function is executed. I am just not following how to assign the different classes to different cell. Because as I mentioned all are going oto animate. I just need a bit of an explanation here. Thanks for the response mate

Comment: I understand. But you don't know how to do it in code or storyboard editor?

Comment: I know about creating other class. I am just not following how will creating a new class help. Its not about getting a specific cell of index path to run an animate function. What i want is similar to instagram liking a post. so when you like a post, a hear appears. But its for that specific cell. I hope i am able to clear you. It may be that i am not able to fully understand you, would you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

in your function **tableView(cellForRowAt)**, write the code like following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    ...
    return currentCell
}
```

Comment: Yes! I am sorry, I didn’t notice the ‘for’. Although when i try it, i doesn’t quite change anything.

Comment: add 'for', it's another function. it doesn't change anything?

Comment: By doesnt change anything I meant, its producing the same error. Its still replicating functions for each cell. This is of as liking an image on instagram. When you like a post, the heart appears on the specific cell, not all the cells. I hope i am able to establish my concern. Cheers